# Error creating Groovy class with latest release of IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I  am using the latest version of the Community Edition of IntelliJ Idea ( 2021.2 ) with the Groovy plugin ( 212.4746.92 ) on a Windows 10 box.

I created a very simple Groovy class:

```
class HWClass {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using a simple println statement to print output to the console
        println('Hello World');
    }
}
```

When I try and run the Groovy class I get :

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I have verified my project setup many times ...I have my Platform Settings SDK set to OpenJDK 12 and my Global Libraries references my Groovy 3.0.8 installation. Note that this is a new release of IntelliJ Idea I am using ( 2021.2 ) ...I am aware of a known bug in this release of IntelliJ ( https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275043 ) with Groovy **Scripts** but am unaware of any issues with Groovy **classes**... any thoughts ?

Comment: Probably the issue is related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275889 . Could you attach screenshots from "File | Project Structure | Project" and "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler"?

Comment: My compiler info : openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I have a public GitHub copy of the project at : https://github.com/ramrod1460/IntelliJ_Groovy

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not reproduced for my work environment. Please attach screenshots from "File | Project Structure | Modules | IntelliJ_Groovy | Dependencies" and "File | Project Structure | Project"

Comment: As requested, I have placed screenshots of requested items and of the error creating the simple Groovy script file in the Github project at: https://github.com/ramrod1460/IntelliJ_Groovy